# Return User Meta text as links to post edit inside the user columns

Tags: admin, functions

I use this function to get some information to the user columns,

```
function column_company( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['usercolumn-company'] = __('Company', 'user-column');
    $defaults['usercolumn-myoffers'] = __('Applied Offers', 'user-column');
    $defaults['usercolumn-totaloffers'] = __('Total Offers', 'user-column');
    return $defaults;
}

function custom_column_company($value, $column_name, $id) {
    if( $column_name == 'usercolumn-company' ) {
        return get_the_author_meta( 'company', $id );
    }
    elseif( $column_name == 'usercolumn-myoffers' ) {
        return get_the_author_meta( 'offersiget', $id );
    }
    elseif( $column_name == 'usercolumn-totaloffers' ) {
        return get_the_author_meta( 'totaloffers', $id );
    }
}

add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'custom_column_company', 15, 3);
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'column_company', 15, 1);
```

i return the get_the_author_meta( 'offersiget', $id );

and here i get from the db some post id's as text, like: 8,12,51

is it possible to return this, not as a text but as a link to the edit post
(/wp-admin/post.php?post=(8)&action=edit)?

I try this by @hakre

```
return sprintf('<a href="/wp-admin/post.php?post='.get_the_author_meta( 'offersiget', $id ).'&action=edit">'.get_the_author_meta( 'offersiget', $id ).'</a>');
```

and it works but it return one link with all the post id's inside,
is it possible to split them?

any help?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get_the_author_meta()` calls must be returning a string(following your comments), so what you'll need to do is split that string up into an array, loop over it and build an array of links, then join it back together at the end using a seperator.

```
/*
    Meh, no license, do as you want with it..
    Example code
*/
function ids_to_post_editlink( $ids = array(), $seperator = ' ' ) {
    if( empty( $ids ) || '' == $ids )
        return;

    if( !is_array( $ids ) )
        $ids = explode( ',', $ids );

    $links = array();
    $ids   = array_map( 'intval', $ids );

    foreach( $ids as $pid )
        $links[] = "<a href='" . admin_url( "post.php?action=edit&post=$pid" ) . "'>$pid</a>";

    return implode( $seperator, $links );
}
```

Add that function alongside your code, then update your `get_the_author_meta` calls to one of the following..

```
 // Default(space seperated)
 return ids_to_post_editlink( get_the_author_meta( 'your-meta-key', $id ) );

 // Comma seperated 
 return ids_to_post_editlink( get_the_author_meta( 'your-meta-key', $id ), ', ' );

 // Pipe seperated 
 return ids_to_post_editlink( get_the_author_meta( 'your-meta-key', $id ), ' | ' );
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Happy to help.. :)

Comment: I consider that a derivative work of mine :P

Comment: Consider it all you like.. ;)

Comment: lol, i got a downvote, i seriously hope that's not for my comment above, or comments at the top of the code i provided, code of which i could of written with my eyes closed(and i'm not joking either). Be curious to hear why someone down-voted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as you're concerned to build a link based on the postID, this is some example code:

```
/**
 * Copyright 2011 by hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/>, some rights reserved
 *
 * Provided AS-IS, example code only. 
 *
 * Licensed under CC BY-SA 2.5, needs attribution.
 *   * Author: hakre <http://hakre.wordpress.com/> 
 *   * Where : With the code and the visible portion of 
 *             any remixed work.
 * Exceptions to this need the written form.
 *
 * If you make use of this code, please send me a deposit copy, thx.
 */
# get the link for a specific postId
$getPostIdLink = function($postId) {
    return sprintf('/wp-admin/post.php?post=%d&action=edit', $postId);
}
$getHtmlOfLinks = function($postIdsCommaSeperatedText) use ($formatPostIdLink) {
    $links = array_map(function($postId) use ($formatPostIdLink) {
        $postId = intval(trim($postId));
        if ($postId) {
            $link = $formatPostIdLink($postId);
            return sprintf('<a href="%s">(%d)</a>', $link, $postId);
        } else {
             return false;
        }
    }, explode(',', $postIdsCommaSeperatedText));
    $links = array_filter($links);
    return implode(', ', $links);
}

echo $getHtmlOfLinks('8,12,51'); # do the output, 
# should give you (8), (12), (51) [brackets are linked]
```

or for your updated question:

```
return $getHtmlOfLinks(get_the_author_meta( 'offersiget', $id ));
```

Comment: i use this and i get one link with (12,21,123)ids, i will update the question!

Comment: I updated the code, this one is splitting your comma separated list of IDs.